# Using Newtonsoft.Json in wcf service get error

Tags: c#, wcf, json.net

Hi I used Newtonsoft to build the WCF service in C#. I also have a test website to test my service. When I viewed the WCF service in the browser, it shows.
If I used the website to call the service, there is the error :

> "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

I didn't closed the WCF service in browser. I am not sure whether the website or WCF service cause the error.

There is my WCF service:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,         
UriTemplate = "BookingInfo/JSON/")]        
BookingResult Booking (BookInfo bookInfo);




[DataContract]
public class BookInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    public Int64 RoomID;

    [DataMember]
    public Int64 locationID;

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime dateTime;

    [DataMember]
    public string name;
}

[DataContract]
public class BookingResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool isSucceed;
}


public BookingResult Booking(string inputClass)
{
    BookInfo bk = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BookInfo>(inputClass);
    BookingResult result = new BookingResult();
    if (bk.dateTime < DateTime.Now)
    {
        result.isSucceed = false;
    }
    else { result.isSucceed = true; }
    return result;
}
```

There is my method in the website to call the service:

```
private string callService(BookInfo input)
{
    string serviceUrl = "http://localhost:17154/CS/Services/Service.svc/BookingInfo/JSON/";           
    var stringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);      
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    string rtn = client.UploadString(serviceUrl, "POST", stringPayload);
    return rtn;
}
```

Comment: This error has nothing to do with JSON.NET. It means the wrong URL was used. The `UriTemplate` attribute of the service is "BookingInfo/JSON/" but the URL ends at `BokingInfo`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, is that enought for a Typo ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I corrected the URL. Now I got a new error, "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

the 404 you are experiencing is not related to `Newtonsoft.Json` in any way.
Your `OperationContract` specifies **BookingInfo/JSON** in the `UriTemplate` property of the `WebInvoke` Attribute

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",UriTemplate = "BookingInfo/JSON/")]        
BookingResult Booking (string bookInfo);
```

therefore the URL for your client should be

```
string serviceUrl = "http://localhost:17154/CS/Services/Service.svc/BookingInfo/JSON/";
```

heres an [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute.uritemplate?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_ServiceModel_Web_WebInvokeAttribute_UriTemplate) link for further info about the `WebInvoke` attribute

Comment: I changed the URL as you suggest, but I got another error, "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Comment: any particular reason you are using the generic `WebClient` instead of `HttpClient` ?
have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/
or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request